# REST api timing out if used with HTTPS

Tags: bash, nginx, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, certbot

I have a REST api hosted on AWS with elastic beanstalk, all the code works as intended when I try to access it through HTTP and the SSL cert is set up correctly as far as I'm aware, I think the problem I'm having is with nginx, but I'm not sure where I have the port 443 open with an .ebextensions config file

```
---
# Open port 443 in security group
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt":["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

# Configure for single instance and apache
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    EnvironmentType: SingleInstance
```

and here's the script that sets up the SSL cert

```
#!/bin/bash
# IMPORTANT: use this bash otherwise following error: "failed with error exit status 127. Stderr:/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory"
# IMPORTANT: use LF instead of CRLF for .sh files, otherwise following error: "00_ssl_setup_certbot.sh: no such file or directory"
# IMPORTANT: for LF: also set "* text eol=lf" in ".gitattributes" file otherwise git will convert it into CRLF again on Windows :(

set -euo pipefail

# Postdeploy script for enabling SSL (single instance)
# Compatible only with Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instances

LOG_PATH=$(find /var/log/ -type f -iname 'eb-hooks.log')
DATE=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

# IMPORTANT: no whitespaces in CERTBOT_NAME, otherwise following error: "invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:81"
CERTBOT_NAME='Sealion'
CERTBOT_EMAIL='<email>'
# Multiple domain example: CERTBOT_DOMAINS='bort.com,www.bort.com,bort-env.eba-2kg3gsq2.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com'
CERTBOT_DOMAINS='<URL>'

LOG_PATH=$(find /var/log/ -type f -iname 'eb-hooks.log')
log_level() {
    if [ -n "$LOG_PATH" ]; then
        DATE=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        echo "$DATE | $1: $2" | tee -a "$LOG_PATH"
    fi
}

log_debug() { log_level 'DEBUG' "$1"; }
log_info() { log_level 'INFO' "$1"; }
log_error() { log_level 'ERROR' "$1"; }

# Variable check
log_debug "Check certbot variables"
if [ -z "$CERTBOT_NAME" ] || [ -z "$CERTBOT_EMAIL" ] || [ -z "$CERTBOT_DOMAINS" ]; then
    log_error 'Certbot and/or proxy server information is missing.'
    exit 1
fi

# Install EPEL
# Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html
log_debug "yum: Install EPEL"
if ! yum list installed epel-release; then
    yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
fi

# Install certbot
log_debug "yum: Install certbot"
if yum list installed epel-release && ! command -v certbot &>/dev/null; then
    yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-nginx
fi


HTTP_STRING='^http\s*{$'
NAME_LIMIT='http {\nserver_names_hash_bucket_size 192;\n'

# Prevent replace if not clean sample app
if ! grep -Fxq "$NAME_LIMIT" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; then
    # Increase size of string name for --domains (for default EB configs)
    
    log_debug "nginx: Increase name limit"
    if ! sed -i "s/$HTTP_STRING/$NAME_LIMIT/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; then
        log_error 'Changing server name limit failed'
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# Set up certificates
if command -v certbot &>/dev/null; then
    log_debug "nginx: Check configuration"
    if nginx -t; then
        log_debug "certbot: Install nginx configuration"
        certbot --nginx \
          --cert-name "$CERTBOT_NAME" \
          --email "$CERTBOT_EMAIL" \
          --domains "$CERTBOT_DOMAINS" \
          --redirect \
          --agree-tos \
          --no-eff-email \
          --keep-until-expiring \
          --non-interactive
    else
        log_error 'Nginx configuration is invalid.'
        exit 1
    fi
else
    log_error 'Certbot installation may have failed.'
    exit 1
fi

# cron: Attempt to renew certificates twice a day (to account for revocations, etc.)
cat >> /etc/cron.d/certbot_renew << END_CRON
MAILTO="$CERTBOT_EMAIL"
42 2,14 * * * root certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade --deploy-hook "service nginx reload && service nginx restart"
END_CRON
chmod +x /etc/cron.d/certbot_renew

log_info 'Script ran successfully.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to test connectivity using `curl` command.

1. On localhost.
2. From remote host.

Suggest to inspect and configure firewall.

In Red Hat based Linux (RHEL, Centos, Fedora, Oracle...), read this [article](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-centos-7-with-firewalld/).